# Checkbox is not displaying in the ngDialog popup

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-dialog

I am using the likeastore\ngDialog library for pop-ups, I am trying to add checkbox in the pop-up but it's not getting displayed.

I tried to update the version from 0.5.7 to 1.4.0 but nothing helped. There is no custom CSS as well![enter image description here][1]

attached screenshot below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUesy.png

Comment: why not use the bootstrap modal? I have been using bootstrap modal with angularjs for a while and have not had any issues

Comment: are you adding the checkbox dynamically? please provide a fiddle if possible

Comment: It's an existing application, I need to stick with ngDialog. It's a static one.

Comment: html is not visible in your provided screenshot

Comment: That's the HTML for two text box and a checkbox. (html is auto adjusted).